# constructing a matrix in excel vba

Tags: excel, matrix, vba

I need help in constructing a n x n matrix, where n is equal to the number of remaining stocks at time t for t = 0, ..., 10. Initially, I have in total 10 stocks, which I will discard one by one as time goes by.

Each element of the matrix will be equal to sigma(i) x sigma (j) x rho , where sigma(i)=sigma(j) = 0.25 and rho=0.2

And the last thing I want to do is to multiply that matrix by the transpose of that matrix

I am really confused where and how to start, and really thankful for your help

```
Sub Matrix() 
'Sigmai 'Sigmaj 'Rho 
    Dim Sigmai, Sigmaj, Rho As Single 
    Sigmai = Range("b12").Value 
    Sigmaj = Range("b13").Value 
    Rho = Range("b14").Value 
    Dim matrixelement(10, 10) As Single 
    For n = 1 To 10 
        For m = 1 To 10 
            matrixelement(n, m) = Sigmai * Sigmaj * Rho 
            Cells(n, m) = matrixelement(n, m) 
        Next m 
    Next n 
End Sub
```

Comment: please can you add some screen prints of your existing data structure and also an example of the table you are aiming to get?

Comment: have you been playing with pivot tables at all to find a solution?

Comment: From your description you have a 10x10 matrix with all values equal. Not sure that's what you want...

Comment: to get a transposed version of a table it might be good to use the `OFFSET` function

Comment: Sub Matrix()

'Sigmai
'Sigmaj
'Rho

    Dim Sigmai, Sigmaj, Rho As Single
    
    Sigmai = Range("b12").Value
    Sigmaj = Range("b13").Value
    Rho = Range("b14").Value
    
        Dim matrixelement(10, 10) As Single
        
        For n = 1 To 10
        For m = 1 To 10
    
        matrixelement(n, m) = Sigmai * Sigmaj * Rho
        
        Cells(n, m) = matrixelement(n, m)
    
        Next m
        Next n
    
End Sub

Comment: i have tried to construct the matrix and above commands is all what i got..

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of basic problems with your code, which you should clear up before progressing.  See comments in code below:

```
Sub Matrix()
    ' declare ALL your variables
    Dim n As Long, m As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' specify type for all variables, otherwise they will be Variant
    Dim Sigmai As Single, Sigmaj As Single, Rho As Single

    ' Explicitly reference the required sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1 ' or ActiveSheet or whatever

    ' qualify range references with worksheet
    Sigmai = ws.Range("b12").Value
    Sigmaj = ws.Range("b13").Value
    Rho = ws.Range("b14").Value

    ' Specify required lower bound. Default base is 0
    Dim matrixelement(1 To 10, 1 To 10) As Single
    For n = 1 To 10
        For m = 1 To 10
            matrixelement(n, m) = Sigmai * Sigmaj * Rho
        Next m
    Next n

    ' return result to sheet in one go
    ws.Range("A1:J10") = matrixelement

End Sub
```

For the

> > And the last thing I want to do is to multiply that matrix by the transpose of that matrix

part, I not sure what you are after exactly, but `MMULT` may be usefull, eg

```
ws.Range("L1:U10") = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(matrixelement, matrixelement)
```

Comment: +1 lovely code. `ws.Range("A1:J10") = matrixelement` is slick

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass go on the array and put the result straight to the worksheet. A worksheet if effectively just one big 2 dimensional array.

Cannibalising Chris Neilsen's code:

```
Sub Matrix()
' declare ALL your variables
Dim n As Long, m As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

' specify type for all variables, otherwise they will be Variant
Dim Sigmai As Single, Sigmaj As Single, Rho As Single

' Explicitly reference the required sheet
Set ws = Sheet1 ' or ActiveSheet or whatever

' qualify range references with worksheet
Sigmai = ws.Range("b12").Value
Sigmaj = ws.Range("b13").Value
Rho = ws.Range("b14").Value

For n = 1 To 10
    For m = 1 To 10
        ws.cells(n,m).value = Sigmai * Sigmaj * Rho
    Next m
Next n

End Sub
```

a couple of things I don't understand:

- if b12/b13/b14 are all constants then surely every number in the matrix will be the same ?!
- if every number is the same then multiplying by the matrix transposed will just have the square of every number in each cell of the matrix ?!

Comment: The reason to calculate into an array is efficiency: touching the sheet inside a loop is much slower than calculating into an array.  Posting code like this just encourages bad practice.  That said, for a small number of cells, the difference will not be noticable.

Comment: +1 chris ... although "Posting code like this just encourages bad practice." is a little harsh!